# Meteor + Onsen UI + Monaca cloud build

Tags: cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui, monaca

I want to use Onsen UI for a mobile application on Meteor. And I also want to use the cloud build from Monaca for this. Is it possible?
As I see the Meteor project has a completely different structure. But I understand that eventually they both do the Cordova project. What should I do to add to the Meteor Project the possibilities of the Monaca project? Does anybody have this experience?
Maybe there is a step-by-step tutorial to create a Meteor project, add Onsen UI to it, and then add parts of Monaca to use the Monaca cloud build?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Meteor. So, I'm not sure if this is gonna work. But you can try. 
If the project you are developing on Meteor is a Cordova project, it might also work in Monaca. You can try exporting your project from Meteor then import it to Monaca as a new project. Then, you can use the build features in Monaca.

Or if you haven't started developing with Meteor yet, why not just start developing on Monaca from the start? It's even easier to develop when Onsen UI is a built-in feature with Monaca.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Yes I have experience with Onsen UI and Monaca but I need Meteor for realtime communications between server and client. Unfortunately Meteor project have some specific structure and this framework generate Cordova project from Meteor sources "on the fly" when you execute "build" command.